# Capture focus event for all textboxes - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have many textboxes in a form. When its respective value fails validation a class 'has-error' is applied, which adds a red border to the textbox.

I would like to undo this class if that textbox get focus.

Something like

```
$(document).on('focus',find(':input'),function(){
    $(this).removeClass('has-error');
});
```

How is this done?

Comment: Thank you all. Eduardo's solution worked. But it's deleted. Anything wrong with it. `$("input:text").focus(function () { $(this).removeClass('has-error') });`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `find(':input')` just use `':input.has-error'`

```
$(document).on('focus', ':input.has-error' ,function(){
   $(this).removeClass('has-error');
});
```

---

And also make sure your code in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: It's worth noting that the focus event doesn't bubble, jQuery just fakes it.

Comment: @tymeJV - focus and blur events [do not bubble up the chain of parent elements](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html), they are only available on the elements that triggered the event, so those events can't really be delegated to a parent element, as the event doesn't bubble up to the parent element. However, jQuery fakes it internally so all events bubble, so in jQuery it *does* work, that's why it's worth noting, it's not standard behaviour, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$(document).on("focus", "input:text.has-error", function() {
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same, I'm not sure of OPs needs but it wont work for dynamically loaded elements AFAIK.

Comment: @Trufa -- Classes are applied based on validation - this works off that.

Comment: Ohh, I just realized I might have changed the premises of the question, give me a second.

Comment: Nope... unless I'm getting something wrong (I might) this wont work if the form is loaded dynamically...

Comment: @Trufa -- Ahh, my bad. Thought the form was already there and the elements within were changing. Edited.

Comment: No problem! I'm pretty sure from the question that that wasn't actually a requisite, but since the original had that form of $(document) so I didn't thought it was wise to change it.